# Divide cell in excel by 3 different string patterns using vba

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a list with a row in excel which has three different types (pattern) of string:

1. ABCD, CBFG, EXAL

For the first type it's for example:  **ABCD**

So it will always be a combination of letters and no numbers or anything else.

2. ABCD (HOLA), CBFG (HOLA), EXAN (HOLA)

For the second type it's for example:   **ABCD (HOLA)**

So it will be always a combination of letters and a combination of letters in brackets.

3. ABCD (HOLA), SOLE, CBFG (HOLA), SUPRA, EXAN (HOLA), ITAN

For the third type it's for example:     **ABCD (HOLA), SOLE**

So it will be always a combination of letters and a combination of letters in brackets and a comma followed by another combination of letters

All these three types are listed with the following pattern.

Let's say we have: ABCD and ABCD (SOLE) and ABCD (HOLA), SOLE

Then my cell will look as follows:

ABCD, ABCD (HOLA), ABCD (HOLA), SOLE

Now I have the type 3 which also includes a comma. You can say there are two different commas here. One is used to divide each entry and the other one 
is actually a part of one entry.
What I am trying to do now is to get these three types and paste them into another cell.

I don't know how to go about this. If someone can give me an advice on how to start that would be great.

[Here is an example how I want my cell to divide the information:
In B2 is the information I have. The range H1 to J4 is what I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li7gO.png)

Comment: Is it fair to say a quick way to look at this is: Your cell will have an even number of items. You want to group these items in groups of Two, with each group in its own column?

Comment: How does someone distinguish between a comma separating type 1 values and a comma that is included in the type 3 string? For example what if your third row in `Row B` contained _ABCD (HOLA), SOLE, CBFG (HOLA), SUPRA, EXAN (HOLA), ITAN, ABCD, CBFG, EXAL_, how can you tell _ABCD_ isn't included in _EXAN (HOLA), SOLE_?

Comment: Is there a list of words designated as suffix: SOLE SUPRA ITAN?

Comment: As Dan notes, your patterns aren't mutually exclusive.  That's a problem.

Comment: @Dan thank you for pointing that out. I should correct my question. The three types ar ein fact not listed at random. For example if you have ABCD and ABCD (HOLA) and ABCD (HOLA), SOLE then the cell will list it as ABCD, ABCD (HOLA), ABCD (HOLA), SOLE.

Comment: Will the three types always occur in that order (Type 1 comma-separated values followed by Type 2 comma-separated values followed by Type 3 comma-separated values) in any given row? If so, there is no ambiguity and the splitting point between Type 2 and Type 3 can be distinguished.

Comment: @D_Bester not yet. but it would probably easier that way.. I can get a list for suffix since they will always be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soshiribo,
I think that will would work for you. You would obviously want to rename and define all of the variables and change the limits on the loop but this should work.

```
Dim string2() As String
For I = 1 To 3
    Erase string2()
    string1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 2)
    string2() = Split(string1, ",")
    x = UBound(string2) - LBound(string2) + 1

    Select Case x:
        Case Is = 5
            String3 = string2(0) + "," + string2(1)
            String4 = string2(2)
            String5 = string2(3) + "," + string2(4)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 4) = String3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 5) = String4
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 6) = String5
    Case Is = 6
            String3 = string2(0) + "," + string2(1)
            String4 = string2(2) + "," + string2(3)
            String5 = string2(4) + "," + string2(5)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 4) = String3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 5) = String4
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I + 1, 6) = String5
    End Select

Next I
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a regex, here's an idea:

```
(\w+)( \(HOLA\))?,? ?(SOLE|SUPRA|ITAN)?
```

I don't fully understand all the requirements, so this is really just a starting point.